# Translate page.tpl.php strings

Tags: 7

I have a custom slideshow and the phrases are all in page.tpl.php (please see figure attached)
But they are not dynamic, so they are in PT.

Now I have a multilingual site (I installed all the necessary modules) and everything in my site is working great.

My question is: How can I translate those strings in page.tpl.php to English everytime I switch to EN in my site? Does it require much coding?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just edit the `page.tpl.php` file and wrap all text in `t()` function.

For example:

```
<p>This is a sample string.</p>
```

Turns into:

```
<p><?php print t('This is a sample string.'); ?></p>
```

EDIT: this will make those strings translatable. After that, use the translation interface to find those strings and translate them in other languages.
If your original question was about where you can translate those strings in the admin, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks! After doing that I went to Config > Regional and Language > Translate interface > searched for my strings and translated them!

Comment: Yep, that was it. Glad it helped.